# Show Current User Location with MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I am trying to show current location of user by setting the property of `MKMapView`  i.e `setShowsUserLocation` to `YES`. As by default an arrow appears on the top left of iPhone screen when the application starts updating the user location.But after showing the current location the arrow should disappear but its still present as long as the app is running which would mean the app is still updating the location in the background? so how can i stop updating the current location? i have implemented the delegate which gets called up immediately..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the map is visible and has showUserLocation set to YES, it continues to update in the background.

You need to unset this when the view disappears or when the Application goes to background. The best way would probably be to register your viewController to be notified for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appToBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appReturnsActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```

Then in the method called by this notification, change the map view properties regarding `userLocation`:

```
- (void)appToBackground{
  [mapview setShowsUserLocation:NO];
}
```

And

```
- (void)appReturnsActive{
  [mapview setShowsUserLocation:YES];
}
```

Check that these methods are indeed called by setting a breakpoint there and returning to the home screen.

Comment: I've been using this method, but am getting what appears to be a race condition crash when entering the background: `[MKMapView(UserPositioning) stopUpdatingUserLocation]` calls `[MKMapView(UserPositioningInternal) removeUserLocation]` which blows up with a SIGSEGV. Don't suppose you've seen/solved this already?

Comment: need to remove observer when `viewDidUnload` ?

Comment: @MichaelKernahan I am getting the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @horsejockey - Try setting the `mapView` delegate to `nil` before removing the user location.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Michael Kernahan, I'm pretty sure there is a race condition inside `MKMapView`.

`MKMapView` appears to try to remove the `userLocationAnnotation` (the blue dot) by itself as soon as it realises it lost access to location services.

However, that does not seems protected and if the developer also issues a `[mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO]`, it is very likely to get a crash because of the race between `MKMapView`'s internal thread trying to remove the `userLocationAnnotation`, and the thread that is calling `setShowsUserLocation:NO`.

Comment: Agreed. This does seem to be an issue in iOS 7.x in particular. I don't think I've yet seen it on 8.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop updating the location by sending a message to the location's manager  `[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`

As for your case, did you try to stop showing the users location?

Comment: i am not using any location manager.. if i stop it, it hides annotation(location) too

Comment: Try implementing `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, you'll have a better way of controlling CoreLocation Framework.

You can find a good starting tutorial over here: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application