# MKMapView - Setting showsUserLocation to NO causes a crash

Tags: ios, mkmapview, segmentation-fault

It looks like I am getting some crashes reported when I hide the user's location on a MKMap instance by setting the showsUserLocation property to NO. The cause is SIGSEGV and the following is what I see in the reported stack trace.

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce it on my device but I was wondering if anyone has experienced this before since it is a rather strange bug. Digging around, I came across this post, [Show Current User Location with MKMapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924653/show-current-user-location-with-mkmapview), but seems like there is no real explanation yet.

```
MapKit   _contains(objc_object*, MKQuadTrieNode*) + 10
MapKit   -[MKQuadTrie contains:] + 25
MapKit   -[MKAnnotationManager _removeAnnotation:updateVisible:removeFromContainer:] + 51
MapKit   -[MKAnnotationManager removeAnnotation:] + 29
MapKit   -[MKMapView(UserPositioning) stopUpdatingUserLocation] + 117
```

My code is just pretty simple.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    _map.showsUserLocation = NO;
}
```

Note that all crashes seems to come from various devices running iOS 7.0.3 and 7.0.4.

Comment: Seeing a very similar crash, but it doesn't seem to be related to "showsUserLocation". I have no useful information on the crash reports, so I'm trying to figure something out by sort of guessing what is wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672959/mkmapview-showsuserlocation-crash

Comment: getting the exact same issue... anyone found a solution yet?